# How to use mult-catch clause?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x=3,n=5,d=0;
    int ar[]=new int[3];
    String name="Neno";

    System.out.println("Start main");
    try{
        ar[x]=name.charAt(n)/d; //n=5
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("String index Error");
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println("Any runtime Error");
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Array index Error");
    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Arithmetic Error");
    }

    System.out.println("End   main");
}
}
```

I used this code to filter some exceptions,but there is an error in the code. It says to remove the catch-clauses of `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` and `ArithmeticException`. Is it because the order of the catch-clauses the error springs up? When I change the order like this...

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x=3,n=5,d=0;
    int ar[]=new int[3];
    String name="Niroth";

    System.out.println("Start main");
    try{
        ar[x]=name.charAt(n)/d; //n=5
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("String index Error");
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Array index Error");
    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Arithmetic Error");
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println("Any runtime Error");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Any Error");
    }

    System.out.println("End   main");
}
}
```

There was no error in this order. Can anyone explain me the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Catching exceptions is like buckets placed one after another.You must cacth broader ones in the last. Hope the following *diagram* helps:

Wrong:

```
 \                           /
  \_____RuntimeException____/

      \                  /
       \__AIOBException_/        //ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

      \                 /
       \__AriException_/        //ArithmeticException
```

Correct:

```
      \                  /
       \__AIOBException_/        //ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

      \                 /
       \__AriException_/        //ArithmeticException 

 \                           /
  \_____RuntimeException____/
```

Comment: A smiley for the ASCII art and good analogy :-)

Comment: :D Great Explaination....

Answer (score 4):

You must catch specific exceptions before their superclasses (more broader exceptions, ie `RuntimeException` and `Exception`)

See here for the same question/answer: [Order of catching exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964882/order-of-catching-exceptions-in-java)

Comment: Yes It is a good explaination. But is there any other way we have to consider when considering the order of multi catch clauses?

Comment: As far as I know, in terms of the ORDER of catching, the only rules are that specific exceptions must be written first. My link goes into a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order of `catch` clause matters

This is my logical explanation.

When you have

```
catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Any Error");
}
catch(RuntimeException e){
   System.out.println("Any runtime Error");
}
```

you can imagine that every an exception occurs, it is caught in `Exception` clause, the other block `RuntimeException` will never be reached/used.

Answer (score 1):

Both `ArithmeticException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` extend `RuntimeException` (the last two via `IndexOutOfBoundsException`) - so in your first code snippet, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` catch  won't ever be reached.

You should always catch the most specific exceptions first and finish off with the least specific, as you do in the second code snippet.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, order matters. The first catch clause matching the exception will be executed, and the rest ignored.

As a side note, generally you should **not** catch `RuntimeException`. `RuntimeException` most likely means your logic is wrong or you're not doing the proper checkings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the exceptions from most specific to least specific.

In your first example `RuntimeException` is somewhere in the middle of the `catch` blocks before `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `ArithmeticException`, which are both `RuntimeException`s.

That means the catch block for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or `ArithmeticException` will never be reached since they extend `RuntimeException` whose catch block will handle the exception.

By ordering the exceptions from last specific to most specific (according to the class hierarchy) you give every exception a shot at resolving the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should be caught from more specific to generalized. In other words, catch an exception of subclass before its superclass.

```
try
{
int e=33/0;
}

catch(ArithmeticException e)
{
//code here
}

catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: yes, it is a clear explaination