# Priority between OutOfMemoryError and Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, error-handling

I want to ask which catch block will be called first, in case of statement something like

```
try {
  ...some statement...
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("out of memory exception");
} catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
  System.out.println("out of memory error");
}
```

here statement causes `OutOfMemoryError`.
I have checked [Order of catching exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964882/order-of-catching-exceptions-in-java)

This is something different, You can't predict that there would be a `RunTimeException` occurs if code runs seamlessly.

Comment: Exceptions and errors are orthogonal (they have a common supertype, but one is not the supertype of the other). An exception is caught if an exception is thrown, an error is caught if an error is thrown.

Comment: In case of low memory OutOfMemoryError catch block will be executed with app crash

Comment: @EJP your duplicate concerns only Exceptions, this question is slightly different (Exception vs. Error). (Yes probably it's still a duplicate somewhere else ;) but not this one)

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk-Jun The issue is exactly the same whichever pair of `Throwables` you choose. If there is an inheritance relationship, the compiler will enforce it, otherwise there is no problem to solve.

Comment: @EJP well... yes... but... it's not that clealry answered for throwable siblings, but only for exception siblings. Less experienced people could find this one useful for understanding exception vs. error.

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk-Jun It doesn't make any difference what the siblings have in common. That's why it's a duplicate. General principles apply. Otherwise we would have to have hundreds of answers to essentially the same question.

Comment: @PratikPopat In the case of `OutOfMemoryError`, it will be caught by the corresponding `catch` block *instead* of an application crash, unless the error recurs.

Comment: @EJP I tried with OutOfMemory catch block but still app crashing

Comment: @PratikPopat Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is completely illegible. I have no idea what you're trying to tell me, if anything.

Comment: @EJB This is not duplicate as you suggest.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pls keep in mind the Object hierarchy:

- Java.lang.Throwable

  - Java.lang.Exception
  - Java.lang.Error

If something goes wrong, it's either an ERROR, or an EXCEPTION. There is no first here, as these classes are siblings, not parent/child.

Comment: In my case, I am getting force application close by using only `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Exception and java.lang.Error(OutOfMemory is an Error) are not related to each other exception for their common parent Throwable. So there's no first or second here.

OutOfMemory happens when your jvm is dying(heap full) which is rare, so just do cleanup work inside that.

Comment: 'Rarely"?  `OutOfMemory' *always* happens when your heap is full.

Comment: Your jvm will rarely go out of memory but when it does, it will surely throw OutOfMemory Error

Comment: That's not what it says in your answer.

Comment: @EJB What happens if statment in my case force jvm to throw `OutOfMemoryError`?