# Order of Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a method that throws an `MalformedURLException`. I catch the exception with `try-catch`.
But instead of catching the `MalformedURLException`, it jumps to the `EJBException`.

```
try {
    myMethod(); // throws an exception
} catch (WebApplicationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // I expected the debugger to jump to that line
} catch (EJBException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // debugger jumps to this line
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

StackTrace:

```
WARNING:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB MyClass, method: public com.name.AnotherClass com.name.MyClass.myMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.net.MalformedURLException
WARNING:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    [...] // much more text...
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    [...] // much more text...
FATAL:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    [...] // much more text...
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    [...] // much more text...
```

As [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964882/order-of-catching-exceptions-in-java):

> If the first catch matches the exception, it executes, if it doesn't,
>   the next one is tried and on and on until one is matched or none are.

In my example `MalformedURLException` fires first, as you can see in the 1st line:

```
throws java.net.MalformedURLException
```

Only the 2nd line says:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
```

So, why does it immediately jumps to `EJBException`, if `MalformedURLException` fires first?

Comment: @Shashwat: My question is differs, it's more specific. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check of the EJBException's `ex.getCause()`. The MalformedURLException is wrapped by the EJB container's magic.

One might imagine somewhere a

```
try { ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new EJBException(ex); // Cause: ex.
}
```

Comment: There is no suitable constructor found. That would work: `EJBException((Exception) ex)`. Is it what you mean?

Comment: You are right; corrected from Throwable to Exception. (I did not intend for you to use this. Just that such a kind of wrapping happens.)