# Java ClientProtocolException exception priority

Tags: java, exception

in Java
ClientProtocolException extends IOException
my question is if I want to catch both individually for logging purposes
what should be the order of the catch clause and why?

```
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        throw Exception("got ClientProtocolException ")
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw Exception("got IOException")          
    }
```

Comment: What you have shown is the correct way. Catch the more specific exception first. What's the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964882/order-of-catching-exceptions-in-java

Comment: VHS,  I am not sure, there is some confusion, e.getMessage() is empty, and it seems like one catch is catching the other.

Comment: what is i am throwing  Exception inside each? will the and i got ClientProtocolException?